# how to display object property in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I would like to know how to display object property in ejs template.

object getting from server:

```
urldata = { 
  country: 'Singapore',
  scn: 'SG',
  sccy: 'SGD',
  rcn: 'India',
  rccy: 'INR',
  amt: '1000' 
}
```

ejs template:

```
<%- urldata.country %>
```

Above code is not working. Please help

Comment: `<%- urldata.country %>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan thanks for prompt reply but its not working.

Comment: actually, I'm not familiar with EJS templates, anyways try this as well `<%= urldata.country %>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan It works for whole object like <%= urldata%>, if i access the object property its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `urldata` as *context* to your view on your `app.js` page.

For example:

```
app.get('/someRoute', function(req, res) {
    res.render('someTemplate', {
        urldata:urldata,
    });
});
```

Now on `someTemplate.ejs`:

```
<%= urldata.country %>

<%= urldata.scn %>
```